# How to migrate out of designsync to git/hg/bzr/svn?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, bazaar, dssc

design sync uses RCE as a backend store. RCE is supposed to be the next version of RCS.
Does anyone has any experience with migration of design sync or RCE to any of the newer version control system?

Comment: Did you successfully migrate? How?

Answer (score 0):

I have no direct experience of RCE or RCS, but this SO thread may prove useful:

[Migrate project from RCS to git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619737/how-to-migrate-project-from-rcs-to-git-solved)

Comment: I had actually been through the referred thread before posting my question. My Problem was that since I was seeing a SYNC folder instead of a CVS or RCS folder in my repo I was not sure if the matadata information would be same between RCE and RCS and if not how can it be aligned?
Regards
Vijay

Comment: Sry, can't help you there! :(  I stumbled on that thread and posted it up in the hope it would help, but my personal experience with the tech involved just isn't enough to help out... Hope you get it sorted though! :)