# Add text string to an image file using Python

Tags: python, gif

I have a set of GIF files in which I need to insert a specific string at anywhere inside the binary file but it should not be visually different. I could probably do it in an hex editor but not sure where, as it may corrupt the file.

This is a requirement by by my source control system where it is checked for "$Header $" string in each file before they are checked in.

I have many files so need to do this using python.

Comment: Normally you should be able to write after the end of a `GIF` without breaking it (at least for browsers and image editors). However, `GIF89a` also has some support for textual metadata. Take a look [here](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/GIF) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format)

Comment: This isn't a requirement of RCS itself. It handles binary files just fine. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619737/migrate-project-from-rcs-to-git) may be relevant all the same.

Comment: @DJV thanks Appending it at the end worked fine, I don't see any distortion in the image however checking in still failed , let me check Cairnarvon 's answer