# converting cvs repositories to git

Tags: git, cvs

How to convert a CVS repository to a git repository?

- I have tried using `git cvsimport` command like this:

  `git cvsimport -v -d :pserver:thillaiselvan@(my_cvs_server_root) -r cvs -k (module_name)`
- But the process stalls in the middle for minutes with this message:

  `cvs [rlog aborted]: could not chdir to file_name_config: Permission denied`
- Despite that a directory is created with `.git` but shows fatal error when trying to check git log:

  `git log`

  `fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'`
- On checking the status:

  `git status`

  `On branch master`

  `Initial commit`

  `nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)`

Comment: This question is woefully incomplete. How long is a long time? seconds? minutes? hours? days? How big is the CVS repository? Is it still burning the CPU/doing IO while it waits? What debugging have you done so far? In general: what makes you think there is an "issue"?

Comment: Please add more information.  Have you run with verbose options, do you get partial results, do you get log files?  Also perhaps you want to look at Tailor if you have an issue with Git's CVS support (though Tailor also struck me as buggy, last time I looked).  http://progetti.arstecnica.it/tailor

Comment: @Daniel: It is taking more minutes. Some times it is saying error message as "cvs rlog aborted" permission denied likewise

Comment: @progetti.arstecnica.it/tailor: Though it stops in the middle, I got the .git directory. But when I am running git log command it says like this "fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'". If I run git status it says "# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
"

Comment: When executing the "git cvsimport -v -d :pserver:thillaiselvan@(my_cvs_server_root) -r cvs -k (module_name)" command, in the middle it says like "cvs [rlog aborted]: could not chdir to file_name_config: Permission denied". From there it keeps on waiting. No further things happening.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a migration tool from CVS to Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881158/is-there-a-migration-tool-from-cvs-to-git)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use `git --bare cvsimport -d:local:/cvsroot/$PROJECT -v -k -m -i -A Authors -o master $PROJECT` to import cvs project from the local repository (or mirror) into a local bare git repository that is suitable for being exposed to remote developers. This can do incremental updates if you are still using CVS as the primary repository.

However you should also look at [cvs2git](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2git.html) as this can be better sometimes but is more appropriate for a one-off conversion to git. `cvsimport` can have trouble with vendor branches so it is important to very carefully check your newly imported repository. In both cases it can take a long time for large repositories (possibly hours on a slower machine with a 10year old cvs repository).

Comment: Why it is saying the message like "cvs [rlog aborted]: could not chdir to file_name_config: Permission denied" How to overcome from this?

Comment: That looks like a message from your remote CVS server to me. You will speed things up a lot if you create a local mirror of the CVS repository and use local access rather than pserver. That should help to eliminate any permissions issues as well. For instance, sourceforge permit use of rsync to copy cvs repositories and that can then be used to convert to git.

Comment: Ok. Now I am having a exact local copy of a repository which has several versions, branches, tags etc., Say the repository name is project1. It is under /home/thillaiselvan/project1/. Tell me a command to convert this to git repository. Thanks in Advance!