# How to import and keep updated a CVS repository in Git?

Tags: git, cvs, git-svn, git-cvs

There is a central repository in CVS, and I would like to use it with Git locally, and then send my changes back to CVS.

What can I accomplish that on a daily basis?

The tasks I would like to accomplish are:

- importing branches,
- getting history in GIT-like format, and
- exporting back my changes/commits to the centralized server

BTW, I have also looked at [Best practices for using git with CVS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595106/best-practices-for-using-git-with-cvs) . But It didn't work and I couldn't figure out what I missed or did wrong.

Comment: You should explain why git-cvsimport doesn't work for you. Also for this question git-svn is totally unrelated (or provide a link if there is a tool svn-git which deals with CVS).

Comment: @honk, I believe git-cvsimport is only one way ticket to Git

Comment: @AlexeyShytikov, there is still `git-cvsexportcommit` to get your work into the CVS repo. While not the same awesomeness as `git-svn`, it is still much more useful than plain CVS.

Comment: @honk you right I've missed that point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a migration tool from CVS to Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881158/is-there-a-migration-tool-from-cvs-to-git)

Comment: I really can't understand why this has to be closed. "opinion-based" ? A how-to  of  copying a source repository back and forth?

Comment: Here is an effective tool I just used for a long delayed migration: https://github.com/rcls/crap

Answer (score 58, accepted):

What I have done in the past is:

### Import the CVS repository

Using:

```
$ git cvsimport -C target-cvs -r cvs -k -vA authors-file.txt -d $CVSROOT module
```

Where:

- `target-cvs` is the directory to keep my local copy of the repository.
- `cvs` is the name to use for referencing the remote repository. So, I will have `cvs/master`, `cvs/HEAD`, etc. pointed locally by `master`.
- `authors-file.txt` is the file that contains the matches between CVS account and Name+email, each line contains `userid=User Name <useremail@hostname>`
- `$CVSROOT` is the CVS respository server.  If I use an anonymous cloning from some sourceforge repository, then I would use: `:pserver:anonymous@project_name.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/project_name`
- `module` is the module inside of the repository I want to clone.  If the repository has only one module, then likely will be the same as `project_name`.

### Update the repository

It is possible to repeat the command I wrote previously.  In that particular example, it should be run in the parent directory of `target-cvs`.  To make it easier in the future, you might want to configure some variables (you can read more details in the answer of  *"[How to export revision history from mercurial or git to cvs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584522/how-to-export-revision-history-from-mercurial-or-git-to-cvs/586225#586225)"*)

```
$ git cvsimport
```

That would be enough to keep the local repository in `git` synchronized with the remote one in CVS.

### Daily work

From now on, every change should go in a local git branch.  One feature, one branch. For this, I use a work flow described in "*[A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)*".  The only difference is that *master* points to CVS, but conceptually the same work flows can be applied here.  It is just a convention.

Once your commit is pushed in CVS, it will be back to master in the next update (`git cvsimport`).  Then, you can remove the local branch that implemented that feature.

For work in progress (in local branches), you should `rebase` them against master.  Because you have the features separated, it should be easier to solve conflicts.  The tricky part is when some branches depend on others, but still manageable.  Micro commits helps a lot (as in any git work flow).

If every local branch is rebased and master never touched (except for updates), then `git 
cvsexportcommit` should just work.  Remember, it works for one commit.  It is a bit tedious, but it is better than nothing.  Given the previous example the command should be something like:

```
$ git cvsexportcommit -vc commit-id
```

If you only have read-only access to the remote CVS, then you can send the patches by email or make your git repository public, so the commiters can grab your patches to apply them.  Nothing different from a normal work flow of CVS in this case.  Again, in the next update you will see the changes in *master*.

Comment: I had to install `cvsps` on OSX (`brew install cvsps`). However it's broken by `cvsps: bad usage: invalid argument --norc.` error. This happens for cvsps 3.x (the option has been removed), possibly downgrading it to 2.x could work, but it could cause other problems.

Comment: @kenorb: git-cvsimport doesn't work with csvps 3.x but 2.x. In order to install an earlier csvps, run `brew uninstall cvsps; brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew/5a0b551194b5cf8017478432f8f7e63a77c12bd1/Library/Formula/cvsps.rb`

NOTE: I'm blind. Didn't see your answer below

Comment: The [cvsimport](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cvsimport.html) man page is full of warnings, deprecations, and more warnings. It recommends the use of cvs2git instead.

Comment: Sure, 4 years after the original answer.

Comment: Sometimes answers need to be amended when new information becomes available.

Comment: Agreed. As anybody can edit them, rather comment it you could have edited it. couldn't you?

Comment: unfortunately outdated

Comment: On Windows, I get _git: 'cvsimport' is not a git command._

Answer (score 7):

With recent version `git cvsimport` is broken, because of `cvsps` [tool incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9609943/55075).

So you've to install `cvsps-2.1`.

On OSX you can (having `brew`):

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install cvsps2
brew unlink cvsps
brew link --overwrite cvsps2
```

And import on empty git repository as usual, e.g.:

```
git cvsimport -C RepoName -r cvs -o master -k -v -d:pserver:anonymous@reponame.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/path ModuleName
```

---

You can also use [`cvs2git`](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/%7Ejacob/cvs2svn/cvs2git.html) tool which can convert a CVS repository to git. However you need to have access to a CVSROOT directory.

Check [cvs2git documentation](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/%7Ejacob/cvs2svn/cvs2git.html#docs) for installation steps.

Example usage:

```
cvs2git --blobfile=git-blob.dat --dumpfile=git-dump.dat --username=cvs2git /path/to/cvs/repo
```

This would create two output files in git fast-import format. The names of these files are specified by your options file or command-line arguments. In the example, these files are named `cvs2git-tmp/git-blob.dat` and `cvs2git-tmp/git-dump.dat`.

These files can be imported into empty git repository by:

```
cat git-blob.dat git-dump.dat | git fast-import
```

Then delete the `TAG.FIXUP` branch and run `gitk --all` to view the results of the conversion.

Check for more, by running: `cvs2git --help`.

Comment: `brew tap homebrew/versions` throws
`Error: homebrew/versions was deprecated. This tap is now empty and all its contents were either deleted or migrated.` nowdays

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is no ready to use recipe in your case. But, you can try following:

- Manually synching CVS data with Git, or write scripts for that. They will get information from CVS and put it to Git. This will give you some kind of history in Git. Not fully clean, not fully usable, but still.
- Migrate your CVS repository to Git using [tools](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2git.html) like `git cvsimport`. And ask Git to pretend to be CVS for other developers, using `git cvsserver`.

Comment: Here the success story of migration to Git from CVS: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9609943/1047741