# Migrate from CVS to Git without losing history

Tags: git, version-control, cvs

I need to know if there is a way to migrate my code from CVS source control to Git?

If yes, what about my history of commits?

Comment: here there is a good answer to your probleme :)

http://stackoverflow.com/a/17135045/2718509

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a migration tool from CVS to Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881158/is-there-a-migration-tool-from-cvs-to-git)

Comment: @kolen: Seems like it.

Comment: I couldn't find a good solution to this on Stack Overflow, but I did find a great one at https://superuser.com/a/1451527/120672 .

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've not personally done a conversion from CVS to Git, but I believe Eric Raymond's [`cvs-fast-export`](http://www.catb.org/esr/cvs-fast-export/) is the tool to use.  He has the man page posted [*here*](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/cvs-fast-export/cvs-fast-export.html).  [`cvsps`](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/cvsps/) is another tool maintained by Eric, but it has recently been deprecated in favor of `cvs-fast-export`.  [`cvs2git`](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2git.html) is another tool which is built on some of the same machinery as `cvs2svn`.  The latter was extremely adept, and so I have high hopes that `cvs2git` is equally good.

One thing to note: CVS is a pretty broken RCS.  It's possible that it can have content that can't be reflected exactly in Git.  In other words, there is some impedance mismatch there, but the tools try very hard to preserve as much as possible.  Make sure to check your conversion and that you're happy with the results.  You may need to fixup part of the Git history to get something more acceptable, but I doubt you'll need to.

Comment: `cvs-fast-export` in my opinion has one big flaw ... it uses C. That means it's harder to debug issues, specifically because it outputs stuff on stdout and reads from stdin. It also renumbers the CVS revisions from how they appear in the RCS file which can be confusing if you try to pinpoint issues. Still, this should be the accepted answer. +1

Comment: I tried cvs2git at first, but it depends on anydbm package and a dbm engine other than the default. By the time you've installed all the required Python libraries and gotten it to run, you've done 10x the work of downloading and compiling cvs-fast-export, which doesn't need any external libraries. I found that cvs-fast-export did an excellent job of converting my CVS repositories.

Answer (score 31):

Here is the process I used to migrate a SourceForge CVS repo to Git using [cvs2git](https://github.com/mhagger/cvs2svn) ([latest stable release is here](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/), but IIRC I used the github dev version), which works on both Windows and Linux without any compilation required since it's just Python.

Also, you **don't need to own the repo** with this method, you can for example migrate SourceForge projects that you don't own (you just need the right to checkout, so this works on any public repo).

> How to import from sourceforge CVS to git.
> First, you need to download/checkout the cvs repo with the whole history (not just checkout the HEAD/Trunk):

```
rsync -av rsync://PROJECT.cvs.sourceforge.net/cvsroot/PROJECT/\* cvs
```

> then use cvs2git (python script, works on all platforms, no compilation needed):

```
python cvs2git --blobfile="blob.dat" --dumpfile="dump.dat" --username="username_to_access_repo" --options=cvs2git.options --fallback-encoding utf-8 cvs
```

> this should have generated two files `blob` and `dump` containing your whole cvs history. You can open them in a text editor to check that the content seems correct.

> then initialize your git repo inside another folder:

```
mkdir gitexport/
cd gitexport
git init
```

> then load up the exported cvs history onto git:

```
cat ../{blob,dump}.dat | git fast-import
```

> and then place the git commit cursor at the end of history:

```
git reset --hard
```

> finally and optionally, you can push to your remote git repository:

```
git push -u origin master
```

> of course you need before to `git remote add origin https://your_repo_url`

Note: `cvs2git.options` is a JSON formatted configuration file for `cvs2git` where you can specify transforms for various things like author names (so that their nicknames will be automagically transformed to their full name after import). See the [documentation here](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2svn.html) or the [included example options file](https://github.com/mhagger/cvs2svn/blob/master/cvs2git-example.options).

Comment: After browsing and trying all the other solutions this one worked for me! :D

Comment: it worked for me too, I had no option of rsync but I could manually copy the repository. remember always copy the projects manually to the folder or do rsync don't checkout.

Comment: On linux you can `apt install cvs2svn` which includes `cvs2git`

Comment: How would I apply your first line, with `rsync`, when My CVS root is a "pserver"?

Comment: @einpoklum I'm sorry but I'm not very much experienced with CVS so I can't answer your question, maybe someone else can? You can also try to play with the command until it works, or use TortoiseCVS that may ease the process.

Comment: Even though this answer states that cvs2git works on all platforms, I was unable to get it to work on Windows, because apparently cvs2git uses the locally installed CVS client to perform a local checkout (`:local:`). The Windows CVSNT client doesn't support this and fails with `cvs [checkout aborted]: Couldn't open default trigger library: No such file or directory`. Fortunately, the CVS client in Cygwin does support local checkouts and running cvs2git in a Cygwin installation completed successfully.

Answer (score 12):

You can [use `git-cvsimport`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cvsimport.html) to import your CVS repository into Git. By default, this will check out every revision, giving you a relatively complete history.

Depending on your operating system, you may need to install support for this separately. For example, on an Ubuntu machine you would need the `git-cvs` package.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362676/what-is-the-best-way-to-import-a-cvs-repository-in-git-and-use-it-locally#11490134) goes into more detail.

Comment: `git-cvsimport` is more resilient w.r.t. issues in the CVS history, but that yields (silently) incoherent results. I have been reading a lot of answers on SO concerning similar questions and wonder how many people did actual real-world conversions with repositories that have real "scars" and issues.

Comment: In my case: `cvs-fast-export` imported no history, `cvs2git` not even imported a file (error on the example option file), `git-cvsimport` instead did the work with a syntax very close to *This answer* link above

Answer (score 4):

I've used recently (2016) [reposurgeon](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/reposurgeon/) of Eric Raymond to import a CVS repo from sourceforge to git. I was very pleasantly surprised and it worked very well.
After past experiences with cvs2svn and other tools, I recommend without hesitation reposurgeon for this kind of tasks.

Eric has incorporated the migration procedure into Reposurgeon documentation under the title "[A Guide to Repository Conversion](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/reposurgeon/repository-editing.html#conversion)"

Answer (score 2):

I used Docker to run **cvs2git**, using the excellent steps above by @gaborous,
and based on the https://github.com/mhagger/cvs2svn Dockerfile code for cvs2svn.
This has the advantage of having all required tools installed in the image, ready to run.

Follow @gaborous steps above, but replace the python execution with the Docker run.

1. Clone https://github.com/mhagger/cvs2svn to local directory which we will call $DIR.

   cd $DIR
2. Edit Dockerfile

Copy Dockerfile to **Dockerfile-cvs2git** and edit.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["cvs2git"]
```

Build the docker image named cvs2git:

```
docker build --target=run --tag cvs2git . -f Dockerfile-cvs2git
```

3. Copy cvs2git-example.options to cvs2git.options.

cvs2git.options provides two things:

- blob and dump filenames and locations
- CVS sub-module name

Edit **cvs2git.options**

```
..  
blob_filename=r'/tmp/git-blob.dat',  
..  
dump_filename=r'/tmp/git-dump.dat',  
..  
run_options.set_project(  
  r'/cvs/<my-sub-repo>',  
..
```

4. Run the Docker image.

Specify Docker volumes (`-v`) for the CVS root repo location and tmp for the output files location.
Note that cvs2git.options provides the run's configuration.

```
  docker run -it --rm  -v /opt/CVS/<root-repo>/:/cvs -v /opt/tmp:/tmp \
    cvs2git \
    --options=cvs2git.options \
    --fallback-encoding utf-8
```

5. Follow @gaborous instructions above starting with

   mkdir gitexport/
   cd gitexport
   git init

   cat /opt/tmp/{blob,dump}.dat | git fast-import

Answer (score 1):

In order to clone a project from sourceforge to github I performed the following steps.

```
PROJECT=some_sourceforge_project_name
GITUSER=rubo77
rsync -av rsync://a.cvs.sourceforge.net/cvsroot/$PROJECT/\* cvs
svn export --username=guest http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/svn/cvs2svn/trunk cvs2svn-trunk
cp ./cvs2svn-trunk/cvs2git-example.options ./cvs2git.options
vim cvs2git.options # edit run_options.set_project
cvs2svn-trunk/cvs2git --options=cvs2git.options --fallback-encoding utf-8
```

create an empty git at `https://github.com/$GITUSER/$PROJECT.git`

```
git clone git@github.com:$GITUSER/$PROJECT.git $PROJECT-github
cd $PROJECT-github
cat ../cvs2git-tmp/git-{blob,dump}.dat | git fast-import
git log
git reset --hard
git push
```

Answer (score 1):

[gaborous](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e80001f8fd7f608c6d05ce0ab2ebfc90d724a307/Documentation/git-fast-export.txt#L132-L137)'s [answer](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3edfcc65fdfc708c1c8f1d314885eecf9beb9b67/Documentation/git-fast-import.txt#L459-L463) uses [`git fast-import`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/32615ce7626f8f07990bd1c01f49be6dca7d4a2d/t/t9350-fast-export.sh#L97-L118), which could fails on log message *not* encoded in UTF-8.

That will work better with Git 2.23 (Q2 2019): **The "`git fast-export/import`" pair has been taught to handle commits with log messages in encoding other than UTF-8 better.**

See [commit e80001f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e80001f8fd7f608c6d05ce0ab2ebfc90d724a307), [commit 57a8be2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/57a8be2cb0cb6825d25885b34106aab79d6c9853), [commit ccbfc96](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ccbfc96dc480a1395f2068c706f53fe0881c8356), [commit 3edfcc6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3edfcc65fdfc708c1c8f1d314885eecf9beb9b67), [commit 32615ce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/32615ce7626f8f07990bd1c01f49be6dca7d4a2d) (14 May 2019) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 66dc7b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66dc7b68e4a332c662980b0266b9a1cb545f40ff), 13 Jun 2019)</sup>

> ### `fast-export`: do automatic reencoding of commit messages only if requested

> Automatic re-encoding of commit messages (and dropping of the encoding header) hurts attempts to do reversible history rewrites (e.g. sha1sum <-> sha256sum transitions, some subtree rewrites), and seems inconsistent with the general principle followed elsewhere in `fast-export` of requiring explicit user requests to modify the output
> (e.g. `--signed-tags=strip`, `--tag-of-filtered-object=rewrite`).
> **Add a `--reencode` flag that the user can use to specify, and like other fast-export flags, default it to '`abort`'**.

That means the [`Documentation/git-fast-export`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e80001f8fd7f608c6d05ce0ab2ebfc90d724a307/Documentation/git-fast-export.txt#L132-L137) now includes:

```
 --reencode=(yes|no|abort)::
```

> Specify how to handle `encoding` header in commit objects.

> - When asking to '`abort`' (which is the default), this program will die when encountering such a commit object.

- **With 'yes', the commit message will be reencoded into UTF-8.**
- With 'no', the original encoding will be preserved.

> ### `fast-export`: avoid stripping encoding header if we cannot reencode

> When `fast-export` encounters a commit with an 'encoding' header, it tries to reencode in UTF-8 and then drops the encoding header.
> However, if it fails to reencode in UTF-8 because e.g. one of the characters in the
> commit message was invalid in the old encoding, then we need to retain the original encoding or otherwise we lose information needed to understand all the other (valid) characters in the original commit message.

> ### `fast-import`: support 'encoding' commit header

> Since git supports commit messages with an encoding other than UTF-8, allow `fast-import` to import such commits.
> This may be useful for folks who do not want to reencode commit messages from an external system, and may also be useful to achieve reversible history rewrites (e.g. sha1sum
> <-> sha256sum transitions or subtree work) with Git repositories that have used specialized encodings in their commit history.

The [`Documentation/git-fast-import`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3edfcc65fdfc708c1c8f1d314885eecf9beb9b67/Documentation/git-fast-import.txt#L459-L463) now includes:

> ### encoding`

> The optional `encoding` command indicates the encoding of the commit message.
> Most commits are UTF-8 and the encoding is omitted, but this allows importing commit messages into git without first reencoding them.

---

To see [that test](https://github.com/git/git/blob/32615ce7626f8f07990bd1c01f49be6dca7d4a2d/t/t9350-fast-export.sh#L97-L118)  which uses an author with non-ascii characters in the name, but no
special commit message.
It does check that the reencoding into UTF-8 worked, by checking its size:

> The commit object, if not re-encoded, would be 240 bytes.

> - Removing the "`encoding iso-8859-7\n`" header drops 20 bytes.

- Re-encoding the [Pi character π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_(letter)#Character_encodings_tables) from `\xF0` (`\360`) in iso-8859-7 to `\xCF\x80` (`\317\200`) in UTF-8 adds a byte.

> Check for the expected size.

---

And with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), the pack header created for import is better managed.

See [commit 7744a5d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7744a5d6921c457a05224cd7f5554e972df634b0), [commit 014f144](https://github.com/git/git/commit/014f1447f0382b323b53006a65dd2b8383427dc8), [commit ccb181d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ccb181d0f053100a988ee0a240e3c0c0bb962d4d) (06 Sep 2020) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9b80744](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b8074427bd2bb52d0c7ec876ebe0e6834bb69fe), 18 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`fast-import`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ccb181d0f053100a988ee0a240e3c0c0bb962d4d): use `write_pack_header()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> Call `write_pack_header()` to hash and write a pack header instead of open-coding this function.
> This gets rid of duplicate code and of the magic version number 2 -- which has been used here since [c90be46abd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c90be46abdbd102ab8e9af0303d33976d552ae58) ("Changed fast-import's pack header creation to use [`pack.h`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ccb181d0f053100a988ee0a240e3c0c0bb962d4d/pack.h)", 2006-08-16, Git v1.5.0-rc4 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/41dc7e004491725e74e3fdd1c364b4c0a234574b)) and in [`pack.h`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ccb181d0f053100a988ee0a240e3c0c0bb962d4d/pack.h) (again) since [29f049a0c2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/29f049a0c277be72637f74f1f90a89dccd3475bc) (Revert "move pack creation to version 3", 2006-10-14, Git v1.4.3).

Answer (score 0):

Migration from CVS to Git using **[cvs2svn](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=0&expandFolder=0&folderID=2976)**

> Sharing all step for migration CVS to git
>
> > 1. create directory a cvsProject in anyDir

```
Rsync: your cvs repo:  
 1. $rsync -av  CVSUserName@CVSipAdrress:/CVS_Path/ProjectName/*  ~/anyDir/ProjectName


 2. cd $../cvs2svn-x.x.0 && ./cvs2git --options=cvs2git-example.options

 3. $./cvs2git --blobfile=cvs2git-tmp/git-blob.dat \
          --dumpfile=cvs2git-tmp/git-dump.dat \
          --username=CVS_YOUR_USER_NAME \
          /path_of_step(1)/cvsProject 

 Note: if get any encoding error then add this into above command:"--encoding=ascii --encoding=utf8 --encoding=utf16 --encoding=latin" 

 4. mkdir newGitRepo && cd newGitRepo 
 5. git init --bare
 6. git fast-import --export-marks=/x.x.x/cvs2svn-2.5.0/cvs2git-tmp/git-marks.dat \
  

wow now you are done, now you can push your repo to git..
Referenece : [link1][2] ,[link2][2]
```

Comment: let me know if you face any issue

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had success and a relatively pleasing experience using the "CVS Remote Access Program", or, well, [crap](https://github.com/rcls/crap) (GitHub).

It can apparently handle various intricacies of CVS repositories which none/not all of the other conversion tools can, but I'm not well-versed in the details. Like cvs2git, it also follows the path of dump files which are actuall imported into git using `git-fast-import`.

The reason I'm suggesting it is that when I found a deficiency in it, I was able to add the capability I was missing to the existing code - and it wasn't so terrible. My PR for that is pending as are a bunch of bug reports.