# Transfer CVS repository to GIT repository

Tags: git, cvs

I have a files that are in CVS repository, I need in some way to transfer it to GIT without any conflicts and bugs..What are the risk that I need to take?

The CVS server and the GIT server are set on linux ofcourse

How can I do that?

Anthor question, if I use software that dosent have any git plugin, how can I use git yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeated:

[migrate from CVS to GIT without losing history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869710/migrate-from-cvs-to-git-without-losing-history)

About your second question, you do not need any plugin to use git with any software. You can use it where you want. Otherthing is if you are asking about IDEs with git integration. But again, you can use git directly without them too.

Comment: You mean to use GitBash?

Comment: Yes, when you install git, bash is included.