# Migrating from CVS to git while preserving history for multiple modules?

Tags: git, cvs, cvs2svn, cvs2git

I'd like to migrate an old CVS repo to git, while preserving history.

Here's how I check out the 5 branches that need to be migrated in CVS:

```
branch1:
cvs co -r branch1 sim Login SystemMonitor archiver

branch2:
cvs co -r branch2 par sim Login archiver
cvs co -r branch2_redux editor

branch3:
cvs co -r GEN3 par sim SystemMonitor archiver
cvs co -r GEN3_update1 tms editor
cvs co -r GEN3Sim
...
```

So the issue here is that a single branch specifies:

1. multiple revisions
2. different modules within a single checkout
3. multiple checkouts commands

I'm no expert but it seems like something far too flexible to fit into git where you're limited to checking out one branch/tag at a time.

What I would like to have is:

1. a git repo which contains branch1 through branch5
2. 'git checkout branch3' needs to create the same files on the filesystem as the 3 cvs checkout commands shown above. It's OK if there's extra modules/directories that remain unused if that makes things easier, but I need the same 3 filesets as CVS to also be there so the project builds.
3. preserve commit history of each branch
4. for commits that are the same between different branches, they should also be the same in git. For example the first 75% of commits for the Login module are identical across all branches, so I'd expect them to have the same SHA in git.

Is this achievable, and if so, how?

**What I already tried**
I successfully ran cvs2git on the repo (a very long 10 hours). I ended up with branches like branch1, branch2, branch2_redux, GEN3, GEN3_update1, GEN3Sim (the -r flags). However, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to combine the histories and files of GEN3+GEN3_update1+GEN3Sim into a single branch3.

This is the command I used to convert the repo:

```
cd ~
rsync -avz myusername@cvsserver:/path/to/cvsrepo/ ./cvsrepo_local_copy/
cvs2git --blobfile=~/git-blob.dat --dumpfile=~/git-dump.dat --username=cvs2git ~/cvsrepo_local_copy
mkdir new_git_repo && cd new_git_repo && git init
cat ~/git-{blob,dump}.dat | git fast-import
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import and keep updated a CVS repository in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362676/how-to-import-and-keep-updated-a-cvs-repository-in-git)

Comment: Not at all. Importing a single module into git is trivial and the command I already solves that issue. The issue is foundational differences between git and CVS: I require multiple CVS checkouts of multiple branches of multiple modules to get the correct source code on my filesystem, whereas git only lets you do a single 'git checkout something'.

Comment: Did you try out my suggested answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest modifying (a copy of) the *CVS* repo first and *then* running the cvs2git.

The `,v` files are simply text files with no checksums or anything in them, so you can just edit them.

Something like this, done for all the branches you want standardized to a base branch name.

```
find editor -type f -name '*,v' | xargs sed -i -e 's/branch2_redux/branch2/g'
```

Once you've done that, all your "branch2*" branches should be just called "branch2" and when you run the cvs2git all the files should be created together on the same branch, as you want.

Comment: I would like to try this, however there's an issue which the OP's examples don't include, which is that SOME projects checkout modules which don't mention a specific branch name. For example "cvs co gui" alongside the branch-specific checkouts.

So the standalone 'gui' is checked out on multiple projects (although some older branches keep an older 'gui'). In the absence of an explicit branch name, what can I do?

Comment: If you don't care about history, you could just commit the `gui` module's code to each branch after the conversion. Or it could just be a separate module, using git submodules; that sounds kind of like the use-case involved.