# Importing existing CVS repository to Git alongwith history

Tags: git, cvs, cvs2git

We have a codebase of 12+ years controlled by CVS. We are now planning to migrate to Git.  Are there any tools available that can help in importing CVS along with the history to Git?

I have tried a couple of tools but they are supposed to migrate only the current state of the code but not the history.

Comment: Well, there's `git cvsimport` (which uses `cvsps` behind the scenes), `cvs2git`, `parsecvs`, and probably others...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a migration tool from CVS to Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881158/is-there-a-migration-tool-from-cvs-to-git)

Comment: We used cvs2git and it works really well at preserving all the history, our CVS repository was 20 years old and had 10'000's of commits