# cvs2svn cvs2git: map cvs users to github users

Tags: github, cvs, cvs2svn, cvs2git

I used cvs2git to convert 1 cvs repo to git and push it to github. Everything works except that I don't see any contributors for my repo on github. I am wondering if there is a way to bring all the users from cvs and map them to github users.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881158/is-there-a-migration-tool-from-cvs-to-git

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are ok with converting the repository again, you should use the [author_transforms](https://github.com/mhagger/cvs2svn/blob/master/cvs2git-example.options#L511) field in the options file.

Here is the example from the example options file I linked to:

```
author_transforms={
    'jrandom' : ('J. Random', 'jrandom@example.com'),
    'mhagger' : 'Michael Haggerty <mhagger@alum.mit.edu>',
    'brane' : (u'Branko Čibej', 'brane@xbc.nu'),
    'ringstrom' : 'Tobias Ringström <tobias@ringstrom.mine.nu>',
    'dionisos' : (u'Erik Hülsmann', 'e.huelsmann@gmx.net'),

    # This one will be used for commits for which CVS doesn't record
    # the original author, as explained above.
    'cvs2git' : 'cvs2git <admin@example.com>',
    }
```

The example file has more details.

If you need to keep the existing repo in github, you may be able to do some form of rewriting of the commit history, but I don't know anything about that.